# Vue.jsでaxiosを使い.envファイルにアクセストークンを置いてもブラウザのdevtoolからトークンがばれる

Tags: vue.js, http, axios

Vue.jsでhttp通信を行うために
axiosを使い、使用するアクセストークンは.envファイルに置いているのですが
ブラウザのdevtoolからトークンがばれるのはどうしようもないのでしょうか？
暗号化などを行う方法がありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.jsをブラウザ上で動作させる場合、axiosでHTTPリクエストを行うのもブラウザです。そのため、必然的にブラウザがアクセストークンを知ることになるため、質問者さんのおっしゃる通り、どうしようもないです。

アクセストークンをブラウザ（クライアント側）に知られてはいけない場合、トークンを知っているAPIサーバーを用意し、クライアント（Vue.js）からはそのAPIサーバーに対してリクエストを発行、アクセストークンを用いた実際のリクエストはAPIサーバーが行うという方法をとることになります。